# Using 2d numpy mask np.where to address a 3d numpy array (pythonic??)

Tags: python, numpy, raster, array-broadcasting

Say I have an image array:

```
raster.shape => (3,100,100)
```

I generate a mask of all the places where red is saturated:

```
mask = np.where(raster[0,:,:] == 255)
```

I want to modify the slice of those locations... Which I can do like this:

```
raster[:,mask[0],mask[1]] = 0
```

Is there a more pythonic way... or is this the best bet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the mask directly, e.g.

```
raster[:, raster[0] == 255] = 0
```

which should be the equivalent of what you wrote.

Comment: Now I wonder why I started using np.where in the first place??